# Apache Rewrite returns nothing at all in subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've deployed my website on OVH and I have some issues. It works just fine on localhost and it returns nothing on OVH. Both have the same file structure :

```
/
  www/
    portfolio/
      [others files or folder]
      .htaccess 
      index.php
```

The problem is that I'm using the Apache's rewrite_mod. I have this in my .htaccess file :

```
 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

So everything goes through index.php but I've got litteraly nothing in return. even if I do a simple `echo 'Hello World !'` on the first line. Right now I simply try to access it via www.domain.com/portfolio, I didn't use the `DirectoryIndex` in a `www/.htaccess` file.

Do you have any idea ? Thank you

Comment: What version of apache are you using? Did you enable htaccess use in the apache config? `AllowOverride All` It is not on by default on 2.4

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.2.22 on OVH and 2.4.9 on localhost. Are there huge differences between them ? Is that what may cause some problems ?

Comment: There is enough of a difference to that you need to check your requirements before assuming it will work. You need to check on your OVH that htaccess is allowed for that vhost/location as I mentioned before. Check your apache config and change allowoverride to All.

Comment: You were right, it does work now. Plus, I had to set the php version I needed. Now everything is not perfect but at least I have a Hello World ! Thank you @PanamaJack, If you write an answer I'll flag it as the correct answer

Comment: No problem. Glad you go it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to allow `.htaccess` in your Apache config.  Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`